how does one prove that $|z_1 - z_2|^2 \geq \frac{1}{2} |z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2$
I am working on proving the following inequality for any complex numbers $z_1,z_2$
​$$
|z_1 - z_2|^2 \geq \frac{1}{2} |z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2          
$$
I've attempted to expand both sides of the inequality and simplify it by using properties of complex numbers, but I am struggling to make further progress. Does anyone have any hints or suggestions on how to tackle this inequality?

Let $u = |z_1-z_2|$ and $v=|z_2|$. By Cauchy-Schwarz $2\left(u^2+v^2\right)\ge (u+v)^2$ and then triangle inequality to finish

Let $z_1=a+b$, $z_2=b$. Then triangular inequality is more apparent.

$$|z_1-z_2|^2\stackrel{?}{\geq}\frac12|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2$$
$$(z_1-z_2)\overline{(z_1-z_2)}\stackrel{?}{\geq}\frac12z_1\bar z_1-z_2\bar z_2$$
$$z_1\bar z_1-2z_1\bar z_2-2z_2\bar z_1+4z_2\bar z_2\stackrel{?}{\geq}0$$
$$|z_1-2z_2|^2\stackrel{✓}{\geq}0$$
